# Menu button position

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to use `Tkinter` to make a window and then create buttons at the top left like most programs have, i.e. `File`, `Edit`, `Select`, `View` etc. I can create a button with text, and I've tried different ways to move the position of the button, but, for some reason, it's not working. If my understanding is correct, the top left position when using `.grid` should be `(row=0, column=0)`. So, for verification purposes, I tried using `(row=10, column=1)` and the button is still at the same position. Please help!

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x250")
root.title("D&D Tracker")

menubutton = Button(root, text="File", command=root.destroy)
menubutton.grid(row=10, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `place` would be more suitable for this.

Comment: Did you try putting something in other rows and columns?

Comment: Are you aware that tkinter has support for actual menubars? Is there a reason you're not using that feature?

Comment: Empty rows and columns have a size of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from geeksforgeeks, but what you want is tkinter Menu widget:

```
# importing only  those functions 
# which are needed
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from time import strftime
  
# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Menu Demonstration')
  
# Creating Menubar
menubar = Menu(root)
  
# Adding File Menu and commands
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='File', menu = file)
file.add_command(label ='New File', command = None)
file.add_command(label ='Open...', command = None)
file.add_command(label ='Save', command = None)
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = root.destroy)
  
# Adding Edit Menu and commands
edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit)
edit.add_command(label ='Cut', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Copy', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Paste', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Select All', command = None)
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label ='Find...', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Find again', command = None)
  
# Adding Help Menu
help_ = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Help', menu = help_)
help_.add_command(label ='Tk Help', command = None)
help_.add_command(label ='Demo', command = None)
help_.add_separator()
help_.add_command(label ='About Tk', command = None)
  
# display Menu
root.config(menu = menubar)
mainloop()
```

[**OUTPUT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJM3I.png)

You can use `add_cascade` method to have a menu inside a menu and `add_checkbutton` method for buttons with two states (like auto-start on some programs).

Regarding the tkinter grid, it always starts from the top left corner even if you change row/column value, you need to change `padx` and `pady` values to change it's position within the grid or use `pack()` instead.